# cannot import name 'set_policy' from 'keras.mixed_precision.policy'

Tags: python, keras

when i try to do "from tensorflow.keras import intitializers" i get
"cannot import name 'set_policy' from 'keras.mixed_precision.policy'" this error.
Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

```
tf.keras.mixed_precision.set_global_policy
```

or

```
policy = mixed_precision.Policy('mixed_float16')
mixed_precision.set_global_policy(policy)
```

More info you can find here:

- https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/mixed_precision

Answer (score 0):

go to the error directory and change the import from

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.mixed_precision.policy import set_policy
```

to

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.mixed_precision.policy import set_global_policy
```

or

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.mixed_precision.policy import set_policy as set_global_policy
```